# Upload images when pressing button

Tags: jquery, ajax

There is a way to download the images in the page when you press the button just by jquery ?

I have tried plugin image lazy but will not do the required

```
$('li.tab3').on("click",
  function() {
    $('img.lazy').lazy({ bind: "event", effect: 'fadeIn', effectTime: 2000, });
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. here we expect you to have a go at coding a solution to your problem before asking a question here. We definitely expect you to have tried to google for an answer... eg "image download button jquery tutorial" would be what I'd try first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a way.

Now... what have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: You have tried plugin image lazy but will not do the required

Comment: $('li.tab3').on("click",function() {
        $('img.lazy').lazy({
            bind: "event",
            effect: 'fadeIn',
            effectTime: 2000,
        });
    });

Comment: I'll move this into your original question. Can you tell us: what happens when you run this code? what did you expect instead? (please edit your original question and write it there)